# instantiate Num class in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have Vectorx class and I want to overload `"dot product"`
with operator `(*:)` in Num class

```
data Vectorx a = Vectorx a a a 

instance (Num a)=>Num(Vectorx a) where
    (+) ...
    (-) ...
    etc ...
    (*:) (Vectorx x0 y0 z0) (Vectorx x1 y1 z1) = x0*x1 + y0*y1 + z0*z1
```

It seems to me I can NOT add `(*:)` operator in the instance of `Num`

In Java, I can add whatever method that I want when I implement interface or extend abstract class.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my updated code from suggestion, but I still get "type error"

```
data Vectorx a = Vectorx a a a

class Num a => (VectorOp a) where
    (*:)::Num b=> a -> a -> b

instance (Num a) => Num(Vectorx a) where
    (+) _ _ = undefined

instance VectorOp (Vectorx a) where
    (*:) (Vectorx x0 y0 z0) (Vectorx x1 y1 z1) = x0*x1 + y0*y1 + z0*z1
```

Comment: Then you should construct a new typeclass `DotProductable` (or something similar) with that function.

Comment: Why overload anything? Why not just make `*:` a normal function?

Comment: overload in typeclass so that I can use the same operator (*:) on Matrix typeclass or other typeclasses again, If you have normal function *: then you can not reuse it again,  e.g. on  Matrix typeclass

Comment: Please don't define `Num` instances for vector types, this doesn't make sense mathematically. [`VectorSpace`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.15/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html) is the correct class to use (and [`InnerSpace`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.15/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html#t:InnerSpace) from the same package for dot products).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your case, It is not suitable to subclass `Num` class for calculating `dot product` of vector. it just need to constraint the elements of vector is number as:

```
class DotProduct v where
    (*:)::Num a=>v a ->v a -> a
```

and instance it as:

```
data Vectorx a = Vectorx a a a

instance DotProduct Vectorx where
    (*:) (Vectorx x0 y0 z0) (Vectorx x1 y1 z1) = x0*x1 + y0*y1 + z0*z1
```

You still able to instance `Num` to define `(+), (*)` or etc operations for `Vectorx`, but that is Irrelevant to above `DotPoduct` class.

Comment: data Vectorx a = Vectorx a a a

class Num a => (VectorOp a) where
    (*:)::Num b=> a -> a -> b

instance (Num a) => Num(Vectorx a) where
    (+) _ _ = undefined

instance VectorOp (Vectorx a) where
    (*:) (Vectorx x0 y0 z0) (Vectorx x1 y1 z1) = x0*x1 + y0*y1 + z0*z1

Comment: @AronLee sorry for misunderstanding your question before, I has modified the answer for your case.